# Mouse Wheel scroll shortcut on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

I need to be able to use the mouse wheel scroll function with the keyboard, looked up `setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys` but it has no scroll bindings, only the 3 buttons, what other ways should I explore?